# How far can my SPG shoot?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In *World of Tanks*, the self-propelled guns' (SPGs, or artillery) range is determined much more by projectile motion than the standard LOS guns on the tanks and TDs.  In the spec sheets for the guns or chassis though, it doesn't offer any clue as to how far they can actually shoot.  Where is this information?

Comment: I too would love to see this info, but haven't found any hard numbers yet.  Based on my limited SPG experience, I can tell you that the T57 and the M37 with the stock gun both have very short range...probaby about 500m, while the M37's upgraded gun has good range...probably around 800m to 900m.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/151563-spg-gun-range/

Comment: @Leo you should try to compile the loose data from the forum into a nice post here `;)`  It's a good source; but forum posts are notorious for rotting.

Answer (score 7):

## USA

- **T57**

  - 76 mm Gun (M1918): **520 m**
- **M37**

  - 105 mm Howitzer M3: **440 m** (***480 m*** HEAT)
  - 105 mm Howitzer M4: **960 m** (***1100 m*** HEAT)
- **M7 Priest**

  - 105 mm Howitzer M3: **380 m** (***420 m*** HEAT)
  - 105 mm Howitzer M2A1 **905 m** (***875 m*** HEAT)
- **M41**

  - 155 mm Howitzer M1: **1210 m**
  - 155 mm Gun M1918M1: **1210 m** (***1315 m*** M101M2)
- **M12**

  - 155 mm Gun M1918M1: **1210 m** (***1315 m*** M101M2)
  - 155 mm Gun M1A1: **1315 m**
- **M40/M43**

  - 155 mm Gun M1A1: **1315 m**
  - 203 mm Howitzer M1: **1175 m**
- **T92**

  - 240 mm Howitzer M1: **1250 m**

## German

- **Bison**

  - 15 cm sIG 33 L/11: **465 m**
- **StPz II**

  - 15 cm sIG 33 L/11: **465 m**
- **Wespe**

  - 10.5 cm leFH 16 L/22: **1000 m**
  - 10.5 cm leFH 18 L/28: **1000 m**
- **Grille**

  - 15 cm sIG 33 L/11: **355 m**
  - 15 cm sFH 13 L/17: **710 m**
- **Hummel**

  - 15 cm sFH 13 L/17: **1210 m**
  - 15 cm sFH 18 L/30: **1260 m**
- **GW Panther**

  - 15 cm sFH 18 L/30: **1260 m**
  - 15 cm sFH 36 L/30 Ausf. 1943: **1400 m**
- **GW Tiger**

  - 17 cm K72 (Sf): **1315 m** (***1200 m*** Ausf. G)
  - 21 cm Mrs 18/1 (Sf): **1170 m**
- **GW Typ E**

  - 21 cm Mörser 18/2: **1170 m**

## French

- **Renault BS**

  - 76 mm Schneider: **450 m**
- **Lorraine 39 L AM**

  - Canon de 105 court mle 1935B: **775 m**
  - Canon de 105 court mle 1934S: **840 m**
- **105 leFH18B2**

  - 105 mm leFH18 L28: **1000 m**
- **AMX 105AM**

  - Canon de 105 court mle 1934S: **845 m**
  - Canon de 105 mle 1930 Schneider AM: **1000 m**
- **AMX 13 F3 AM**

  - Obusier de 155 mm C mle.1917: **1100 m** (***1210 m*** H1A)
  - Canon de 155 mm de 33 calibres: **1250 m**
- **Lorraine 155 50**

  - Obusier de 155 mm C mle.1917: **1250 m**
  - Obusier de 155 mm mle.1950: **1200 m**
- **Lorraine 155 51**

  - Obusier de 155 mm mle.1950: **1200 m**
  - Canon de 155 mm L GPF: **1300 m**
- **Bat Chatillon 155**

  - Canon de 155 mm: **1295 m**

## Soviet

- **SU-18**

  - 76 mm Howitzer mod. 1927: **550 m**
- **SU-26**

  - 76 mm Howitzer mod. 1927: **550 m**
  - 76 mm Howitzer mod. 1903/30: **520 m**
  - 122 mm Howitzer mod. 1930: **635 m**
- **SU-5**

  - 76 mm Howitzer mod. 1903/30: **520 m**
  - 122 mm Howitzer mod. 1930: **635 m**
  - 152 mm Mortar NM mod. 1931: **600 m**
- **SU-8**

  - 122 mm Howitzer A-19: **890 m**
  - 152 mm Howitzer ML-20 mod. 1931: **920 m**
- **S-51**

  - 152 mm BR-2: **1140 m**
  - 203 mm B-4: **1230 m**
- **SU-14**

  - 152 mm BR-2: **1295 m**
  - 203 mm B-4: **1210 m**
- **Object 212**

  - 152 mm BR-2: **1315 m**
  - 203 mm B-4: **1225 m**
- **Object 261**

  - 180 mm B-1-P: **1460 m**

— Source: [SPG gun range - General Discussion - World of Tanks official forum](http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/151563-spg-gun-range/page__pid__2938792#entry2938792)

Comment: no british data?

Answer (score 4):

I too wasn't able to find any numbers concerning the range of SPGs. However, range is only a problem/limitation in low-tier SPGs. With almost any mid-tier or high-tier SPG, you can virtually cover the entire map from your starting location. Only few very high caliber guns' range (gw-tiger's, etc.) remains insufficient to reach enemy base in high tiers, which didnot consist much of a problem for me. (I have researched and played up until Gw Type-E and Object-261)

Comment: With some SPGs though (notably Grille with the weaker gun) you can barely reach outside most opponent tanks view range, making them terrible as artillery! It would be worthwhile to know this before you start grinding the 14,000 exp...